# Regex only up-to 32 and 64 from 1

Tags: regex

I want one regular expression in which i want to validate values 
up-to 32 starting from 1 and up-to 64 from 1.

I tried with following: `^1|2|64$` but it is not working, and `^1|2|32$`
but failed to find right answer. Kindly help .

Comment: surely 1 to 64 includes 1 to 32, so I don't see why you mention them seperately.  Please explain what you exactly mean!

Comment: Regex is not an ideal tool for range validation and you're better off parsing it to an int with a built in function. What circumstances bring you to regex?

Comment: Hi Vorspring ,we created two filed where we want to check value only upto 32 and 64 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is probably not a good solution to this problem. Why not just parse it to an integer, then do some simple ">0 && <33" type of check?

However, since you asked, here is my answer:
For 1-32:

```
^(?:(?:3[0-2])|(?:[1-2]\d)|[1-9])$
```

(In action: http://rubular.com/r/oVKeR28T98)

For 1-64:

```
^(?:(?:6[0-4])|(?:[1-5]\d)|[1-9])$
```

(In action: http://rubular.com/r/Zu5Kk3zuDh)

I probably made those regexes a little uglier than they can be, but like I said, this is almost certainly not actualy the answer you should be looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression:

```
^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[012])$
```

will work for **1–32**, and

```
^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[0-4])$
```

will work for **1–64**.

Explanations can be found here:

- [32](http://regex101.com/r/yB9nB7)
- [64](http://regex101.com/r/jY5wK2)

That said, I do not think you should use regex in this situation. A simple check if `num >= 1` and `num <= 32` (or `num <= 64`) should work.

Comment: in simple on one filed when user enter 33 value not accepted ,similarly one second filed when user enter 65 value not accepted.

Comment: @user3134939 Could you word that differently? I can't really understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my perl test program with the regexp for 1 to 32 wired in (altered to not match zero, thanks TimLord)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $r=qr/^([123456789]|[123][012]?|[12]\d)$/;

for my $n (1..32) {
    die $n unless($n =~ /$r/);
}
for my $n (33..64) {
    die $n  if ($n =~ /$r/ );
}

for my $n(65..99) {

    die $n if ($n =~ /$r/ );
}
```

And here's one for 1 to 64, with slightly better testing

```
 use warnings;
use strict;

my $r=qr/^([123456789]|[12345]\d|6[01234])$/;

for my $n(-32..0) {
    die $n if ($n =~ /$r/ );
}
for my $n (1..32) {
    die $n unless($n =~ /$r/);
}
for my $n (33..64) {
    die $n  unless ($n =~ /$r/ );
}

for my $n(65..1000) {
    die $n if ($n =~ /$r/ );
}
```

Comment: That regex matches "0", too!

Comment: @TomLord so it does, naughty me.  Should have tested for it.  Fixed now